# Getting PlayFramework to use Java 1.8 source

Tags: java, playframework

I am having an issue getting PlayFramework to use 1.8 source.

I have installed 1.8 on CentOS and can verify its there with checking the version

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have added the source to my Build.config

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
```

However it has a compile error on any java 1.8 new feature like

```
myProcess.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Compile error new java 8 feature
```

If I set the flag -showversion on my JAVA_OPTION when I start it prints out

```
8.0
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

Final edit
if I enter the play console I get the following output

```
play 2.2.2-RC2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.8.0_11), http://www.playframework.com
```

So it must be the -source and -target options that are being defaulted to 1.7 somewhere.

Comment: `Build.config` -> `Build.scala`, `build.sbt`? In SBT CLI (or by activator), you can try `show javaOptions` & `show javaHome` to gather information about env.

Comment: what do you mean by "show javaOptions" & "show javaHome" are these commands on activator?

Comment: On the CLI, like SBT command `run` or `compile`. And either you have a type about the filename (`Build.config`), or something is wrong/unclear in the question, as Play project is usually described in file named `build.sbt` or `project/Build.scala` so that SBT read it.

Comment: javaHome shows none, says if none will pick up the version on the machine should be 1.8, java options just shows a date strangely. There doesn't seem to be any option for source level

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used alternatives to to install Oracle 1.8 JDK on CentOS and it didn't create any links to javac. So Java had the correct version but javac was pointing to 1.7 OpenJDK

This is what I had to do:

```
cd /etc/alternatives/
ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/javac javac     //Create a symlink to javac
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/javac javac   //In my /usr/bin create a symlink to javac
```